# How can I overcome error messages at Maven Initialization time?

Tags: maven-3

Today I downloaded `apache-maven-3.0.5` and Installed through the following link [Link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=03tRorYADDQ)

after installing, I run the following command for checking whether it's installed or not

`mvn -version`

it showing message like this.

`C:\Users\Infratab Bangalore>mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 19:21:
28+0530)
Maven home: P:\Software\apache-maven-3.0.5
Java version: 1.7.0_21, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "x86", family: "windows"
'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

If you observe above message,I am getting one error, clearly I mentioned error in below

**'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

How can I overcome this.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it,why I am getting this problem `'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`. Because the following path `C:\Windows\System32` was not set in Environment variables. I found through google.I fix it.run same command again it doesn't show any error.